# how to get multiple line inputs in golang - interview coding

Tags: go

For the below type of inputs in golang coding interviews, what is the best way to get the input?

Input:

```
3
hello elloh
test estt
tier riet
```

I found two methods:

Method 1:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

var lines []string

for {
    line,err := reader.ReadString('\n') //this reads only one read

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    if len(strings.TrimSpace(line)) == 0 {
        break
    }

    line_s := strings.Split(line, " ")

    lines = append(lines, line_s...)

}
```

Method 2:

```
bytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)

fmt.Println(len(bytes))
if err == nil {
    input := strings.Split(string(bytes), "\n")
    count, _ := strconv.Atoi(input[0])

    fmt.Println(input)
    var lines []string
    for i := 1; i < count; i++ {
        line := strings.Split(input[i], " ")
        lines = append(lines, line...)
    }

    fmt.Println(lines)
}
```

But not sure how to end getting input from stdin in Method2.

Please suggest the best method to get input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bufio.Scanner` to read input. Use a function to encapsulate complexity and implementation details. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func readData(s *bufio.Scanner) ([][]string, error) {
    var data [][]string
    if !s.Scan() {
        return nil, s.Err()
    }
    nLine, err := strconv.Atoi(strings.TrimSpace(s.Text()))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for ; nLine > 0 && s.Scan(); nLine-- {
        data = append(data, strings.Fields(s.Text()))
    }
    if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if nLine != 0 {
        err := fmt.Errorf("missing %d lines of data", nLine)
        return nil, err
    }
    return data, nil
}

func main() {
    s := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    data, err := readData(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(len(data))
    for _, datum := range data {
        fmt.Println(datum)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/0Xwp3-hwGyK

```
3
hello elloh
test estt
tier riet
3
[hello elloh]
[test estt]
[tier riet]
```